# What is the secret to skin/style dnn navigation menu

Tags: html, css, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-7

I know that this is not real coding issue question but I can't find god resources about this topic.
Although there are few tutorial none of them explain in details with good example how to style dnn menu.
What is the "real world" way to style dnn navigation menu skin?
By the navigation menu I think of menu similar to this:
http://cmstutorials.org/tutorial/view/how_to_build_a_kick_butt_css3_mega_drop_down_menu

http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/css3-dropdown-menu-demo.html

Comment: The secret is `padding`, `border` and `background-color`. You need to use these to model your dropdowns.

Comment: in DNN world it's not just that :)

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry I mistook it to be a *simple* question. The tags threw me off track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret to really learning DNN is to find a skin that looks like you want, and then modify it from there. Unfortunately Skinning tutorials never materialized for the platform (along with a lot of other documentation)

Comment: That is too bad as I saw that there are few ways to make style for nav, ddr menu, razor etc. sometimes this is confusing and lack of dicumentation is real issue.

Comment: I can't say that I disagree with you. Unfortunately there just isn't any desire from DNNCorp to provide documentation

Answer (score 0):

I use the MinimalExtropy - index 1280 skin on my site with a container of MinimalExtropy - Title_Grey, you can them here: http://dnnskins.codeplex.com/releases/view/73347   . If you add a page to the menu it is added to a horizontal bar. Any pages that are children of that page show up in a drop down menu when you hover over it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First, it would help to know which menu system you are using.  Hopefully, your skin uses the newer DDR menu, as it is reasonably well documents in the DNN Wiki at dnnsoftware.com.  This is also information for the older NAV menu, and you can easily replace that with DDR with no other changes required.

As for tutorials, there are some really good skinning tutorials available at DNNCreative.com (disclaimer: subscription is required, and I do work for DNNCreative.  In spite of that, the tutorials are really good.)